# Testing the smart contract for the hardhat fork main network. smart contract for swapping tokens with UniswapV2

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, hardhat

I have file test.js like there:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("UniswapExchange Contract", function () {
  let uniswapExchange;
  let owner;
  let addr1;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    const UniswapExchange = await ethers.getContractFactory("UniswapExchange");
    uniswapExchange = await UniswapExchange.deploy();
    await uniswapExchange.waitForDeployment();

    [owner, addr1] = await ethers.getSigners();
  });

  it("Should swap tokens", async function () {
    const tokenInAddress = "0x7D1AfA7B718fb893dB30A3aBc0Cfc608AaCfeBB0"; 
    const tokenOutAddress = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"; 
    const amountIn = ethers.parseEther("1"); // Amount in wei


    const tokenIn = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", tokenInAddress);
    await tokenIn.transfer(uniswapExchange.address, amountIn);


    await uniswapExchange.swapTokens(tokenInAddress, tokenOutAddress, amountIn);


    const tokenOut = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", tokenOutAddress);
    const ownerBalance = await tokenOut.balanceOf(owner.address);


    expect(ownerBalance).to.not.equal(0);
  });

  it("Should withdraw tokens by the owner", async function () {
    const tokenAddress = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"; // Replace with actual address
    const amountToWithdraw = ethers.parseEther("1"); // Amount in wei

    // Transfer tokens to the contract
    const token = await ethers.getContractAt("IERC20", tokenAddress);
    await token.transfer(uniswapExchange.address, amountToWithdraw);

    // Call the withdrawTokens function
    await uniswapExchange.connect(owner).withdrawTokens(tokenAddress, amountToWithdraw);

    // Check token balance of the owner
    const ownerBalance = await token.balanceOf(owner.address);

    // Assert that the balance has increased
    expect(ownerBalance).to.not.equal(0);
  });
});
```

This is contract.sol file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

interface IUniswapV2Router02 {
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint256 amountIn,
        uint256 amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint256 deadline
    ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
}

interface IERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
}

contract UniswapExchange {
    address private constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address private owner;
    // address private constant WETH_ADDRESS = <WETHAddress>; // Wrapped Ether Address

    constructor() {
    owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function");
        _;
    }   

    function swapTokens(
        address tokenIn,
        address tokenOut,
        uint256 amountIn
        // uint256 amountOutMin
    ) external {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = tokenIn;
        path[1] = tokenOut;

        IERC20(tokenIn).transfer(address(this), amountIn);

        IERC20(tokenIn).approve(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS, amountIn);

        assembly {
            let uniswapRouter := add(0, UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS)
            let pathPtr := mload(0x40)
            mstore(pathPtr, 0x20)
            mstore(add(pathPtr, 0x20), 2)
            mstore(add(pathPtr, 0x40), tokenIn)
            mstore(add(pathPtr, 0x60), tokenOut)

            let swapCallSuccess := call(
                gas(),
                uniswapRouter,
                0,
                pathPtr,
                0x80,
                0,
                0
            )
            if eq(swapCallSuccess, 0) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }

        uint256 swappedAmount = IERC20(tokenOut).balanceOf(address(this));
        IERC20(tokenOut).transfer(msg.sender, swappedAmount);
    }

    function withdrawTokens(address token, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner{
        IERC20(token).transfer(owner, amount);
    }
}
```

Here is the error that occurs during the test:

1. UniswapExchange Contract
   Should swap tokens:
   TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.7.0)
   at makeError (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:678:21)
   at assert (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:702:25)
   at assertArgument (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:714:5)
   at resolveAddress (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/address/checks.ts:122:19)
   at /Users/denys/Desktop/Solidity/Task/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:166:60
   at ParamType.#walkAsync (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/fragments.ts:777:24)
   at ParamType.walkAsync (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/fragments.ts:795:24)
   at /Users/denys/Desktop/Solidity/Task/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:164:22
   at Array.map ()
   at resolveArgs (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:163:37)
2. UniswapExchange Contract
   Should withdraw tokens by the owner:
   TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.7.0)
   at makeError (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:678:21)
   at assert (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:702:25)
   at assertArgument (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/utils/errors.ts:714:5)
   at resolveAddress (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/address/checks.ts:122:19)
   at /Users/denys/Desktop/Solidity/Task/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:166:60
   at ParamType.#walkAsync (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/fragments.ts:777:24)
   at ParamType.walkAsync (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/abi/fragments.ts:795:24)
   at /Users/denys/Desktop/Solidity/Task/node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:164:22
   at Array.map ()
   at resolveArgs (node_modules/ethers/src.ts/contract/contract.ts:163:37)

I put the addresses of tokens the main network from EhterScan. How I can solve this problem? Can somebody help me with this?

I created a new project and forked again, but nothing came out, again this problem. I even made mockups for my tokens, but there are some problems.

Comment: When you ran the test.js on your local hardhat network, did it run successfully?

Comment: I didn’t understand, but I’m running it and it shows such errors, that is, my test does not pass.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that somewhere in your test script when you need you pass an EVM address you pass null

```
UniswapExchange Contract Should swap tokens: TypeError: unsupported addressable value (argument="target", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.7.0)
```

So basically we need to find where is it possible that you passed a null where an address is required.
Let's sum up all of the addresses on your test script:

1. uniswapExchange contract (Dynamic - waiting for being deployed)
2. tokenInAddress (static)
3. tokenOutAddress (static)
4. tokenAddress (static)
5. owner (Dynamic - using getSigners)
6. addr1 (Dynamic - using getSingers) **This one isn't being used so we will ignore it**

If we are certain that for all of the static ones you have put a valid address, it leaves us with the unswapEchange contract & owner addresses.

My guess is that when you are trying to transfer tokens to uniswapExchange you are actually passing a null value, here:

```
await tokenIn.transfer(uniswapExchange.address, amountIn);
```

Now you need to console.log() on your end and test if you indeed have an address when you are accessing *uniswapExchange.address* or *owner.address*

P.S:
I've run your code on my local hardhat project to try and reproduce the error but it seems to be working. Also tried creating two ERC20 tokens for testing it seems to be working as well.

Comment: Hello!

I used .target for contract addresses instead of .address and the error changed. If everything works, can you please send a link to the github, as I have a new problem:
   Error: Transaction reverted: function returned an unexpected amount of data

It seems that the fork of the main network is not working properly, is it better to make a mockup of tokens and try with them?

Thank you for help!

Comment: [GitHub](https://github.com/Dill777/UniswapV2ExchangeContract) - it's my project, maybe problem with some config file? can you check?

Comment: Can you also share the command you are using for running the test?

Comment: The command: npx hardhat test

Comment: so you can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
await tokenIn.transfer(uniswapExchange.address, amountIn);
```

to

```
await tokenIn.transfer(uniswapExchange.target, amountIn);
```

It seems deployedContract.address is now undefined, replaced by deployedContract.target